# How to estimate uncertainty on the prediction from a linear model with errors in the variables?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, linear-model, uncertainty

I have a theoretical model that I am feeding various inputs (initial conditions) and using to generate various outputs (observable quantities). Now I want to take real observations, which have known 1-sigma uncertainties, and determine, assuming the model is true, which initial conditions led to those observations.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have one initial condition $Y$ that I want to model as a function of observable quantities $A$, $B$, and $C$. In R, I do:

```
summary(lm(Y ~ A + B + C))
```

which yields

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ A + B + C, data = DF)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.045731 -0.010079 -0.000647  0.010553  0.043608 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      9.132e-02  1.359e-02   6.718 2.30e-11 ***
A               -1.899e-04  5.451e-06 -34.831  < 2e-16 ***
B               -1.854e-02  4.143e-04 -44.752  < 2e-16 ***
C                7.869e-01  1.563e-02  50.348  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01563 on 2355 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7048,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7036 
F-statistic: 562.3 on 3 and 2355 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now I have observed $A$, $B$, and $C$, each of which having their own observational standard error $\sigma_A$, $\sigma_B$, and $\sigma_C$; and I want to know not only $Y$, but also the uncertainty on $Y$, $\sigma_Y$.

If I simply plug my values of $A$, $B$, and $C$ into that linear model, I can get a confidence interval around $Y$, but this will ignore the uncertainties I have on these values.

My thought is that I can do a Monte Carlo simulation where, in a loop, I can add Normal noise to A, B, and C according to their estimated standard deviations. But how do I properly construct a confidence interval that way? Maybe I can bootstrap the upper and lower bounds?

Advice appreciated. Thanks!